# Im trying to implement a dynamic multi queue system for tickets

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, dynamic, queue

I'm trying to implement a multi queue system for tickets. 
Im using spring boot to receive ticket requests asynchronously.
The requirement is that I am receiving many tickets with specific type key. 
for each ticket I receive, I need to put them in a queue depending on their type key. 
for example, I received ticket with type A, if there is already a Queue for A i should put the ticket inside that queue else, i should create a new queue for type A, and if i get another request A, i need to wait until the first A request finished processing. 
I have uploaded an image to show exactly what i am trying to do.

I wanna know a good approach for this problem. i know how to make a FIFO queue for the requests, but it is hard for me to make the dynamic multi queue.

[dynamic multi queue picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptndG.png)

Comment: Do you know what are all the possible keys of the tickets? Why not having `n` queues where `n` is the number of possible keys?

Comment: @Alexandre Dupriez i do not know all possible values of the keys i need to make my queues such that I get n queues for n distinct requests keys

Comment: If you know in advance `n` is bounded and that bound is "small enough", you can map each key to its own queue. Otherwise, what is possible is to have a single queue from which multiple consumers would poll the requests of a certain key, skipping the elements from the queue which do not correspond to the consumer's key. Order of the requests is preserved. You would need to maintain a cursor for each consumer in the shared queue. Also, for this to be reasonably efficient, we can think of a linked list. How many requests/sec do you have?

Comment: the issue is, i dont know how many keys there are, the only way i can know is when i get them from the requests, also, the requests are asynchronous and random meaning that i could have 50 requests per second or 1 request per day.

Comment: the main objective is when i receive 3 requests each with different key type, i need to process them all at the same time. and if i get 3 requests of the same key type then i need to process them one by one.

Comment: You can have multithreaded consumers polling the queue concurrently. At 50 RPS, you'd need to check carefully there isn't contention on the queue due to locking/synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Create a single queue that is a `Queue<TicketType>`. Call this the master queue.

Create a `Map<TicketType, Queue>` that's keyed by the ticket type, and the value is the queue of tickets for that type.

Create a pool of consumers that monitor the master queue, and process jobs as they come in.

**When a new ticket comes in**

```
if map contains entry for that ticket type
    add new ticket to queue for that ticket type
else
    create new map entry and add queue
    add new ticket to the queue for that ticket type
    add ticket type to master queue
```

**When a consumer gets an entry from the master queue**

```
look up ticket type in map
pull next ticket from the corresponding queue
process ticket
// After ticket is processed:
if queue for that ticket type in map is empty
    remove from map
else
    add ticket type to master queue
```

The idea here is that the map contains one queue for each individual ticket type. The queues in that map each contain all the incoming tickets for that type.

The master queue contains one entry for each ticket type that currently exists in the map. Ticket type A can never have more than one entry in the master queue at any time.

You have to be careful with synchronization here when working with the map queues. You don't want to inadvertently delete a queue that has tickets, for example. It's probably best to lock the map whenever you're adding a ticket, or when you're checking to see if the queue has any more tickets after you've finished processing a ticket. Both of those operations are fast, though, so you shouldn't run into performance problems with bursts of 50 tickets per second. If you're talking a sustained 1,000 tickets per second, you'll probably have to come up with an alternative to the lock.